# Solving a first-follow conflict in a grammar

Tags: grammar, formal-languages, ll-grammar

I'm currently having problems solving this kind of a conflict in a grammar:

```
A -> (A)A'
A -> 0A'
A -> 1A'
A'-> NAND A A'
A'-> eps
```

The problem is that FIRST of A' is NAND - as well as a part of its FOLLOW set. And since there's the A' -> eps rule, that creates a conflict. Is there any way to resolve this conflict? Substitution or factorization don't yield any results - so I guess that I'm missing something.

Comment: How did you conclude NAND was in FOLLOW(A')?

Comment: A'->NAND A A'; A' -> eps; what follows after this rule is FIRST(A'), which is NAND.

Comment: What partial derivation results in ... A' NAND ... ?

Comment: I can't actually find the partial derivation, although I've been following these rules: http://www.jambe.co.nz/UNI/FirstAndFollowSets.html

("If there is a production A → aB, then everything in FOLLOW(A) is in FOLLOW(B)". A can be followed by a NAND (NAND A A' -> NAND A NAND A'). As NAND can follow an A, it can follow B as there's a rule in this form - e.g. A -> 0A'

Comment: And talking about that, there's the partial derivation:
NAND A A' -> NAND 0 A' A' -> NAND 0 A' NAND A A'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that your grammar is ambiguous. For example `0 NAND 0 NAND 0` has at least two leftmost derivations:

```
A => 0 A' => 0 NAND A A' => 0 NAND 0 A' A' => 0 NAND 0 NAND A A' A' =>
  => 0 NAND 0 NAND 0 A' A' A' =>* 0 NAND 0 NAND 0

A => 0 A' => 0 NAND A A' => 0 NAND 0 A' A' => 0 NAND 0 A' => 
  => 0 NAND 0 NAND A A' => 0 NAND 0 NAND 0 A' A' =>* 0 NAND 0 NAND 0
```

rewriting it with ELL syntax it's easier (for me) to see that there are two possible recursions, with A in `NAND A`, or with the star (A' in the original grammar).

```
A -> ( '(' A ')' | 0 | 1 ) ( NAND A )*
```

you could solve the ambiguity making the star the only choice to add NANDs, and using `'(' A ')' | 0 | 1` as its operands:

```
A -> X ( NAND X )*
X -> '(' A ')' | 0 | 1
```